# wysiwyg custom category attribute value not getting in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

I have try to get wysiwyg attribute value in frontend

this is my code :-

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php


namespace Attribute\Categorybanner\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'cat_offer_info',
                [

                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Category Extra Offer Infomation',
                    'input' => 'textarea',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 333,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
                    'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages 

                ]
        );
    }
}
```

**category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- file: app/code/Atwix/CategoryAttribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml -->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="cat_offer_info">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Extra Offer Infomation</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">250px</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cat_offer_info</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.extra.offer.info" template="Attribute_Categorybanner::product/list.phtml" before="category.image"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**list.phtml**

```
<?php if ($_bottomDescription = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getCatOfferInfo()): ?>
    <div class="category-bottom-description">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_bottomDescription, 'cat_offer_info') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please advice me what's wrong. Please suggest me.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

put the below code in your **list.phtml** file,

```
<?php 
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
       $customAttribute = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository')->load($category->getId());
       $customAttributeVal= $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($category, $customAttribute->getCatOfferInfo(), 'cat_offer_info');
                                                

       echo $customAttributeVal;
       
    ?>
```